# Make edges parallel in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

Is it possible to select a number of edges and change their orientation with respect to one of them?

[image: hood]

Comment: Please provide a visual example.

Comment: "change their orientation with respect to one of them" is my question. Align them to each other? Align them to one of them in particular? Align them to a specific measurement?

Comment: @AlexanderESmith Make the middle edge (from selected faces) parallel to the edge either to the right or left.

Comment: GG on a loop  followed by E to make the slide even does this. F flips which side the loop is made even to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in edit mode select the loops you want to move, hit the "G" key twice will allow you to move the loop together.

Also, Propositional option while using the translation gismo

Comment: Maybe you could expand this answer to include the 'E' and 'F' options of the slide tool, which will make the moving loop parallel to an adjacent loop, 'F' flipping which one.